# Dialog Flow Logging to Big query table invalid schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

I am using google cloud  logging to sink Dialog flow requests data to big query. It works for the first 3-4 request but then gives the following Error.
Error Detail
Field `jsonPayload.queryresult.responsemessages.payload.richcontent` is a list of lists, which is not supported by Bigquery.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you also provide the `Build inclusion filter` you are using in your Sink? This is to properly replicate your use case

Comment: logName="projects/adira-feb2022/logs/dialogflow-runtime.googleapis.com%2Frequests"

Comment: This is the Error Details: 
Field jsonPayload.queryresult.diagnosticinfo.execution_sequence.step_3.functionexecution.responses.payload.richcontent is a list of lists, which is not supported by Bigquery

Comment: @Aymal Check your erroneous `jsonpayload` with the correct payload. `list of lists` error suggest that inside payload you have `array of arrays` as  JSON and is not supported by [Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#building_arrays_of_arrays).Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes It is not supported by big query @SayanBhattacharya but how Can i solve it thier is no such help in the documentation. Please help.

Comment: @Aymal You can` t insert  `list of lists` in BigQuery.  You need to make sure either your payload doesn't return that type of data structure or you need to manually parse the payload and format it so that it becomes compatible with BigQuery data types. *Eg.* Pushing log records to **Pub/Sub** and parsing them with **DataFlow** before writing to **BigQuery** can be one of the reasonable workarounds .

Comment: I am having the same issue. I'm using the default Cloud Logs -> Bigquery Sink. It was working as expected, but seems like a change to the Dialogflow API (when you create generative AI content) triggered this error in the log Sink. Hopefully someone from Google can comment on this issue.

Comment: @RonoaldoPereira the best way to do it is using the google Log's API. Get all the Logs based on session id which is unique for each session. Just extract the necessary data from it

Comment: @Aymal thanks - I managed to have at least a way to workaround this. I have created a global organization-level log sink, and the import errors from Dialogflow showed up. Now I can parse this table, adapt the data to the Dialogflow schema and have it ingested there. I do think that the Google-managed sink from Logs->BQ should handle this (as it was previously!); this looks like a bug introduced after Dialogflow started to support gen-ai features. The same bot was having the logs properly ingested and as soon as I added this feature it broke the sink.